# Best switching topology for axial stator with rotating field

Tags: motor, ac, switching, induction, electric-machine

The idea is to have a stator with coils driven by AC current not switched with DC as is done in most cases. On top of that I need the field to physically rotate around with the rotor. This essentially means that each stator coil needs to pass AC current and at certain points needs to be switched from phase-neutral to neutral-phase and vice versa. I have attached a image to show the best way I have imagined this so far, I would welcome suggestions and comments?
The idea is to have coil pairs where each coil is 180 degrees apart and wound in opposite direction, this way by switching on each coil pair I get a N-S pole pair, switching adjacent coil pairs in parallel I can get a two pole N-S field on the stator surface and then by switching pole pairs back and forth between phase and neutral I can get the overall field to rotate with arbitrary speed (speed that is decoupled from the AC frequency) along the stator surface.

My question is what switching scheme best to use for this?

[image: DRAWING]

Comment: Wasn’t it Tesla that figured this out? Looks like you’re trying to re-invent the AC induction motor.

Comment: No @Kartman , the induction motor simply has coils permanently attached to an AC source, the field only rotates metaphorically in that it's strength increases and decreases with time in the coils around the stator. Here I need the field to rotate actually, as the poles change due to the AC, the exact coil always has to match between rotor and stator.

Comment: Is the intent to use a motor to rotate the “stator”?

Comment: @Bryan No, it's a type of rotary transformer , aligning stator poles with rotor ones you can match the waveform and frequency of the stator AC current